# Validation returning “ Undefined index”, because the context data is lost?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have the below code, it keeps giving me       payment_method_id “ Undefined index" error, so I check the debug.log file, it shows

```
2017-11-18 00:27:39 Debug: 7
2017-11-18 00:27:40 Debug:
```

it seems that the validation method is called 2 times, and the first time the $context['data'][payment_method_id] is there, but after that, the second time, it is no longer there? anyone knows how to solve this problem? thanks

```
$validator->notEmpty('cc_expires', __('This field is required'),
                function ($context) {

                    Log::write('debug', $context['data'][payment_method_id]);
                    if ($context ['data'] ['payment_method_id'] == 1 )
                    {
                        return true;
                    }}

                );
```

Comment: found a way around it using this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35544425/cakephp-3-add-conditional-validation

Comment: a way around it, is this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35544425/cakephp-3-add-conditional-validation